# How can I draw polygons on a plot using the locator() function in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, interactive

I am trying to migrate an R script for virtual pumpkin carving to a Shiny app for my students. I want the app to have sliders for "Number of points", which then feeds into the locator() function within the polygon() function in my script. The idea is that you can select the number of polygon vertices (points) with the sliders, then click on the plot to draw polygons.

The script is functional within R, but I'm running into trouble when trying to use the values from two sliders as the input for locator() in Shiny. When I run the app, it displays the following error in place of my base pumpkin plot: "Error: invalid number of points in locator()"

How do I correct the issue so that the app will function in the Shiny environment?

Here is my R script:

```
    #Create base plot
par(bg=1, mar = c(0,0,0,0))
plot(c(0,0), cex=0, xlim=c(-1,1), ylim=c(1.5,0))
X <- runif(500,-1,1)
Y <- runif(500,0,1)
M <- rchisq(500,1)/20
points(Y~X, cex=M, pch=19, col= "white")
points(0,1.1, pch=19, col= "orange",cex=20)
polygon(c(-0.03, -0.08, -0.02, 0.03), c(0.86, 0.76, 0.78, 0.86),
        col = "darkgreen",
        border = "darkgreen",
        lwd = 3, lty = "solid")
#Use the mouse to carve the eyes, clicking at 4 points for each polygon
for (i in 1:2){
  polygon(locator(4),col=7)
}

#Use the mouse to carve the eyes, clicking at 3 points for each polygon
polygon(locator(3), col = 7)

#Now carve the mouth, clicking at 15 points (you can adjust the number of points inside the locator() function below)
polygon(locator(15), col = 7)

# Congratulations, you just carved your first virtual pumpkin with R! You're being a nerd for Halloween!
```

And here is what I have for my Shiny app, so far:

```
    library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Pumpkin Carving with Shiny R"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("points",
                        label = div(h3("Eyes"), em("Number of points:")),
                        min = 1,
                        max = 15,
                        value = 4),
            sliderInput("points1",
                        label = div(h3("Nose"), em("Number of points:")),
                        min = 1,
                        max = 15,
                        value = 10),
            sliderInput("points2",
                        label = div(h3("Mouth"), em("Number of points:")),
                        min = 1,
                        max = 15,
                        value = 10)
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
           plotOutput("Plot")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$Plot <- renderPlot({
        par(bg=1, mar = c(0,0,0,0))
        plot(c(0,0), cex=0, xlim=c(-1,1), ylim=c(1.5,0))
        X <- runif(500,-1,1)
        Y <- runif(500,0,1)
        M <- rchisq(500,1)/20
        points(Y~X, cex=M, pch=19, col= "white")
        points(0,1, pch=19, col= "orange",cex=40)
        polygon(c(-0.05, -0.08, -0.02, 0.05), c(0.6, 0.44, 0.46, 0.6),
                col = "darkgreen",
                border = "darkgreen",
                lwd = 3, lty = "solid")
        
        #Draw eye polygons with locator() using input from the first slider
        for (i in 1:2){
            polygon(locator(points), col=7)
        }
        
        #Draw nose polygon with locator() using input from the first slider
            polygon(locator(points1), col=7)
        
        #Draw mouth polygon with locator() using input from the second slider
        polygon(locator(points2), col = 7)
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User input variables need to be called as `input$abc`.

Try this

```
# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$Plot <- renderPlot({
    par(bg=1, mar = c(0,0,0,0))
    plot(c(0,0), cex=0, xlim=c(-1,1), ylim=c(1.5,0))
    X <- runif(500,-1,1)
    Y <- runif(500,0,1)
    M <- rchisq(500,1)/20
    points(Y~X, cex=M, pch=19, col= "white")
    points(0,1, pch=19, col= "orange",cex=40)
    polygon(c(-0.05, -0.08, -0.02, 0.05), c(0.6, 0.44, 0.46, 0.6),
            col = "darkgreen",
            border = "darkgreen",
            lwd = 3, lty = "solid")
    
    #Draw eye polygons with locator() using input from the first slider
    for (i in 1:2){
      polygon(locator(req(input$points)), col=7)
    }
    
    #Draw nose polygon with locator() using input from the first slider
    polygon(locator(input$points1), col=7)
    
    #Draw mouth polygon with locator() using input from the second slider
    polygon(locator(input$points2), col = 7)
  })
}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks! That fixes the plot rendering issue. However, the interaction component still doesn't seem to be functioning. Though the plot is now visible, I cannot click to draw my polygons from the polygon() functions... any ideas?

Comment: It appears that `locator` is only supported on screen devices such as X11, windows and quartz, at this time - according to the documentation. On other devices the call will do nothing.  So, it will not work as you expect in Shiny.  Perhaps you should consider other javascript options or use polygons to write eyes, nose and mouth.  `points(0.2,.85, pch=19, col= "black",cex=3)`
`points(-0.2,.85, pch=19, col= "black",cex=3)`, will draw eyes.